# How to call a Fragment Activity as a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation Drawer in my Main Activity. Now i need to call all the fragments from `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected` method. But the odd part is that I don't have fragments.All I have activities. So i extended it with `Fragment Activity`.

`MainActivity` is the navigation Drawer Activity.

`FeedListActivity` is the Fragment activity.

Now i need to add the `Feedlistactivity` as a Fragment in my Main Activity. How can i achieve this ?

I saw many questions Related to this. But i can't relate it with me.

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks{

        private Toolbar mToolbar;
        private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
            if (position == 1){
                Fragment newFragment = new Fragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
                transaction.commit();    
            }
        }
    }
```

**FeedListActivity**

```
public class FeedListActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
    private static final String TAG = "FeedListActivity";

    private ListView NewsView;
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    ProgressBarCircularIndetermininate progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed_list);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        progressBar = (ProgressBarCircularIndetermininate) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();
        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        NewsView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.feed_list);
        NewsView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // making fresh volley request and getting json

        // Adding request to volley request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addRequest(gsonRequest, TAG);
        getimg();
    }
}
```

Comment: why you don't extends your class from fragment?

Answer (score 1):

> FeedListActivity is the Fragment activity.
>   Now i need to add the Feedlistactivity as a Fragment in my Main
>   Activity. How can i achieve this ?

A fragmentActivity is not a fragment.  It's an activity with support for fragments, it was introduced to make older android builds backward compatible with fragments -- if you're targeting newer API's only you can ignore it.  To make make FeedListActivity() a fragment...you must extend from fragment.

```
Fragment newFragment = new Fragment();
```

This line here should be creating a new instance of FeedList after you make it a fragment.